Getting OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error with smbus on python (raspberry5) while trying to send data over I2C to Arduino
I connected the Pi5 via i2c with an Arduino Nano.
This is my Pi-Code:
from smbus import SMBus
from time import sleep

addr = 0x8
bus = SMBus(1)
sleep(1)

while 1:
    bus.write_byte(addr, 0x1)
    print("on")
    input()
    bus.write_byte(addr, 0x0)
    input()
    print("off")


This is my Arduino-Code:
#include <Wire.h>

int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin(0x8);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(100);
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  while(Wire.available())
  {
    char c = Wire.read();
    if (c == 0)
    {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
    else
    {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
  }
}


My Error-Message on Pi:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pius/new.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x04,0x02,4)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

What did you try: Everything I can imagine
What where you expecting: reputations and solution
